# How to measure the time a script is running despite system time changes?

Tags: python, time

I'm developing a timeout functionality for an embedded device where the system time is updated via gps. This means I can't just compare two timestamps to get the elapsed time:

```py
import time

t1 = time.time()
# system time change, e.g. from 1970-01-01 to 2022-11-10
t2 = time.time()
elapsed = t2 - t1  # this is now wrong!
```

Is getting the real elapsed time even possible in this case?

Comment: Are you sure `time.now()` exists?. I believe `time.time()` uses epoch time, which I don't think is _timezone dependent_.

Comment: Just checked that `time.time()` [indeed uses](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-time-time-method/) epoch time and independent of whichever timezone you decide to convert to.

Comment: Oh sure it's `time.time()`. Updated it. The problem is not timezone dependence but system time dependence.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification. Worthwhile question as well. Is there a way to just change the displayed time and not the time embedded within the device?

Comment: I need this to check for a connection timeout, so there is no need to display. It's just about the elapsed time.

Comment: which operating system do you have on your embedded system?

Comment: On Linux, the monotonic clock (a clock that cannot go backward) would be useful to find out timeout. https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic

Answer (score 2):

Using [time.perf_counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter)

```
>>> wrong = time.time()
>>> right = time.perf_counter()
>>> # set clock back to correct time
>>> time.time() - wrong
1420070455.9668648
>>> time.perf_counter() - right
42.46595245699996
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a monotonic clock, i.e. a clock that cannot go backwards. **The clock is not affected by system clock updates**. The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of two calls is valid.

Comment: I think this very dependable on the operating system and because of that I am asking it as comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `time.monotonic()`. This is unaffected by system time change. This return response in float. If you want time difference in nanosecond, you can use `time.monotonic_ns()`.

```
import time
t1 = time.monotonic()
t2 = time.monotonic()
elapsed = t2 - t1
```

Ref: You can read about it in detail over official doc: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#:~:text=time.-,monotonic,-()%20%E2%86%92](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#:%7E:text=time.-,monotonic,-()%20%E2%86%92)

Answer (score 0):

## Leveraging CPU cycles and frequency to calculate elapsed time

> Notes
>
> - This approach assumes the embedded device has no [dynamic frequency scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling)
> - Changes in timezone should not affect processing cycles

1. Get the CPU frequency (in Hz)
2. Count the number of CPU cycles required to complete the task
3. Divide the cycle count by the processor's clock speed (in Hz)

### How to count CPU cycles?

[hwcounter](https://github.com/paulsmith/hwcounter)
See an example of how to use [here](https://github.com/paulsmith/hwcounter#example-usage)

### How to get CPU frequency?

See **cpu_freq** in [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil). Note the frequency example [here](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil#cpu)

### Example of how to use the above

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import psutil
from hwcounter import Timer

class Solution:
    def getElapsedTime(self) -> float:
        '''
        Method to get elpased time of a task using cpu cycles
        '''
        max_freq = psutil.cpu_freq().max
        print(f'CPU Max frequency: {max_freq} MHz')

        # Get frequency in Hz = 1/second
        max_freq_in_hz =  max_freq * 10**6

        with Timer() as t:
            self.doTask()

        print(f'Elapsed cycles: {t.cycles}')
        print(f'Duration of task: {t.cycles / max_freq_in_hz} seconds')

    def doTask(self):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(100):
            sum += i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solution = Solution()
    solution.getElapsedTime()
```

#### Output for a 5.3GHz CPU

```bash
CPU Max frequency: 5300.0 MHz
Elapsed cycles: 13238
Duration of task: 2.497735849056604e-06 seconds
```

Comment: It's fancy but doesn't take into account the dynamic frequency scaling most nowadays systems use

Comment: @Wiwild see the note below the title "This approach assumes the embedded device has no dynamic frequency scaling"